# Dynamic accordion not fully working

Tags: html, dynamic, handlebars.js, zendesk

So I have an accordion on zendesk and it's dynamic pulling the content. I a having an issue where only the first tab of the accordion is being collapsed whenever I press any of the the tabs. I think it's because of data-target:

I have it set to open one #id I think i need to make it dynamic but idk how. Can anyone help?

Here is the piece of code:

```
<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" class="article-list article-list_page">
    {{#each section.articles}}
      <li class="article-list__item">
        <a>{{title}}</a>
        <article id="demo" class="article-body collapse">
         {{body}}  
        </article>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add an iterator to the "demo" ID? 
HTML treats IDs as individual items (only one item should have a given ID at a time). It appears that your PHP is iterating through this for each article you are adding to the page, the behavior is working, but any click of any list item would cause the whole thing to behave as you have described. The list would collapse / expand for any item selected.

Maybe something like this:

```
<div class="accordion-wrapper">
  {{#each section.articles}}
  <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#VARIABLE" class="article-list article-list_page">
    <li class="article-list__item">
      <a>{{title}}</a>
      <article id="VARIABLE" class="article-body collapse">
      {{body}}  
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I plugged in `VARIABLE` here, but you would probably keep the syntax you are presently using. Maybe use an ID for the article as the data-target and article ID? (Which would allow you to put in `{{id}}` as a replacement for where I have typed `VARIABLE`)

Comment: Yeah I've been trying {{articles.id}} but zendesk is not allowing it. I think I can't use an article property inside a section page without adding anymore code.

Comment: @DevAnd you should be using `{{id}}` not `{{articles.id}}`

Comment: @Derek I get this error

Error  section_page L94:55: 'id' does not exist

Comment: @DevAnd and you added this inside your `each` loop?

Comment: @AmandaMaring - zendesk uses handlebars, which is javascript, not PHP for templating

Comment: @Derek - so this is something like a JSON object it's attempting to read? I would think your suggestion of using {{id}} should still work if it exists in the returned object.

Comment: Right, kind of. Handlebars takes an object sent from the server and makes all the root level attributes into variables, and then in loops, it uses the attributes of the looped items as variables

Comment: Thank you so much to the both of you! It actually did work! {{id}} @AmandaMaring